# Rename HID - USB GamePad

Tags: usb, hid, gamepad

I'm trying to find out if there is a way to rename the devices as shown in the Game Controllers screen.

[image]

They are cheap HID devices, and they all seem to share the same Hardware ID (if this is relevant information) VID_0E8F&PID_3013

I was able to change their names in the Device Manager following this guide: http://www.eightforums.com/customization/15321-tutorial-how-change-device-names-device-manager.html

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to change the names shown in the image above. I plan on adding 8 game controllers to my PC, and it gets extremely confusing when they all share the same name.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Old post, but the previous answer is incorrect, in case others are looking at it.

In the Registry Editor, navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM\`, click the individual folders and you will see `OEMName`. Double-click that and you can rename each controller. Of course if they are all currently displaying the same name there will be some trial and error for you to figure out which is which, but the changes in the Game Controllers list will be instantaneous, so it isn't be too bad.

Comment: Don't you only have the option of changing the name per unique VID and PID?

Answer (score -1):

The game controller *itself* tells windows its name:

[image: NEUROLAB Pilot Sticks CP]

The name cannot be modified, unfortunately, for almost all commercial USB game controllers.

Comment: wrong. see other/correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67127519/194533