# How can I change name of each two joysticks that are using the same USBComposite instance?

Tags: c++, usb, stm32, hid

I am new to HID devices and creating USB peripherals. As a study project, I created one that uses two joysticks on a single device.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <USBComposite.h>

const uint8_t reportDescription[] = {
   HID_MOUSE_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR(),
   HID_KEYBOARD_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR(),
   HID_JOYSTICK_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR(),
   HID_JOYSTICK_REPORT_DESCRIPTOR(HID_JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID+1),
};

USBCompositeSerial CompositeSerial;
USBHID HID;
HIDJoystick Joystick(HID);
HIDJoystick Joystick2(HID, HID_JOYSTICK_REPORT_ID+1);

void setup(){
  // Setup device
  HID.begin(CompositeSerial, reportDescription, sizeof(reportDescription));
  while (!USBComposite);
  Joystick.setManualReportMode(true);
  Joystick2.setManualReportMode(true);
}

void loop(){  
  Joystick.send();
  Joystick2.send();
}
```

This code snippet uses: https://github.com/arpruss/USBComposite_stm32f1 (library)

https://github.com/arpruss/USBComposite_stm32f1/blob/master/examples/twojoysticks/twojoysticks.ino

**The problem is that when I try to calibrate them, both joysticks have the same name. Thus many programs in which I want to use this device on lose their settings for each run.**

[image]

Unfortunately, the solution to manipulate the instance of USBComposite changing it's VendorID and ProductString or manually changing their name in regEdit as is proposed here:

[Rename HID - USB GamePad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35261124/rename-hid-usb-gamepad)

and https://www.stm32duino.com/viewtopic.php?t=624

doesn't work for me, because it again changes the name so that both joysticks have the same one.